# Ben and Jordan have three coins between them. Two of them are fair but one of them has a 4/7 chance of showing heads.

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

Now, Ben and Jordan both flip each coin once and write down the outcomes.

**What is the probability they both get the same number of heads?**

---

My approach:

4 possible outcomes: 3H, 3T, 2H&1T, 2T&1H.

$P(3H) = (\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{4}{7} *\binom{3}{1} = \frac {36}{84} $

$P(3T) = (\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{3}{7} *\binom{3}{1} = \frac{27}{84}$

$P(2H,1T) = \frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{4}{7} + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{3}{7} = \frac{11}{84}$

$P(2T,1H) = \frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{3}{7} + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{4}{7} = \frac{10}{84}$

P(same number of heads) = $(\frac {36}{84})^2 + (\frac{27}{84})^2 + (\frac{11}{84})^2 + (\frac{10}{84})^2 = \frac{1123}{3528} \approx 32\% $

What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand where these factors of $3$ and $\frac13$ come from.  Isn't the probability of $3$ heads $\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac47=\frac4{28}$?  Both fair coins show heads and so does the biased coin.  Why multiply by $3$?

Comment: @saulspatz I was thinking that the rigged coin could be any of the 3 coins so you have 3 chances and thus $\binom{3}{1}$.

Comment: No, only one of the coins is biased.  The answer given by mihaild is absolutely correct.

Comment: You can consider different places of biased coin if you want, but then you need not only count number of different places, but also multiply by probability of biases coin being in this place.

Comment: @mihaild yeah that's why I was multiplying by 1/3 and 2/3, but I messed it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to multiply by binomial coefficient or in any other way consider different orders of coins. We can simply say that first and second coins are fair, and the last is weighted.

For example, $3H$ means simply that both fair coins and weighted came heads, thus $P(3H) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{7} = \frac{1}{7}$.

Similarly, $2H, 1T$ means that either both fair coins came heads and weighted came tail, or first fair came tail and the rest came heads, or second fair came tail and the rest came tail, so $$P(2H, 1T) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{7} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{7} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{7} = \frac{11}{28}$$

After finding correct probabilities for all possible numbers of heads, you need to sum their squarees, as you did.

Comment: thank you. So following this approach the answer should be 123/392.